# What might pm-trace do that would fix a suspend/resume issue?

Tags: suspend

I've been having trouble resuming from suspend in Ubuntu 19.10. To try to locate and fix the issue, I tried using pm_trace as described [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend). However, when I set the pm_trace flag by running (as root) `echo 1 > /sys/power/pm_trace`, it fixes my resume issue until the next reboot. That is nice as a workaround, but I don't really want to be doing a pm_trace all the time. So my questions: what could pm_trace be doing that would fix my resume issue? What could this mean the problem is? And what could I do to fix such a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original resume issue was caused by asynchronous suspend/resume, which is enabled by default. The reason that resuming from suspend worked when using pm-trace is because pm-trace disables asynchronous suspend/resume as mentioned [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/s2ram.txt). To disable asynchronous suspend/resume, it is only a matter of clearing the /sys/power/pm_async flag with `echo 0 > /sys/power/pm_async`. To have this work after reboots, create a systemd unit to clear the flag on every boot like [this](https://forums.intel.com/s/question/0D50P0000490PBRSA2/nuc-failure-after-linux-sleep-hibernate-suspend-solution).